# How to use nextPageToken to retrieve contacts list from google api. Working example

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, google-contacts-api

I´m using this code to retrieve my contacts list inside a firebase function following the
(https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/people/contacts.js) example

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const clientAuth = require('./clientAuth');

exports.getGoogleContacts = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  console.log('getGoogleContacts- init function')

  const contacts = google.people({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: clientAuth.oAuth2Client,
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    clientAuth
      .authenticate(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts'])
      .then(async () => {

        console.log('after client auth')

contacts.people.connections.list({
  resourceName: "people/me",
  pageSize:200,    
  personFields: ['addresses',
      'ageRanges',
      'biographies',
      'birthdays',
      'braggingRights',
      'coverPhotos'], // ... and many other fields

}, function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
      console.log('contacts.people.connections error')
      console.log(err)
      reject(new Error(err))
  } else if (response) {
      console.log('contacts.people.connections response')
      console.log(response)
      if (response.pageToken) {
           // how could I continue to retrieve next page of contacts?
      }
      resolve(response)
  }
})

      })

  })
})
```

If there is a nextPageToken, there is no working example I´ve was able to found.

## edited - this code was able to solve the pagination with array concatenation

I was able to come up with this solution, even though now I´m facing a problem of pushing to the connections array... It´s not working

```
const listOptions = {
    resourceName: "people/me",
    pageSize: 200,
    personFields: ['addre...']
}

async function getConnectionsList(contacts, nextPageToken) {
    if (!nextPageToken) {
        return contacts.people.connections.list(listOptions)
    } else {
        listOptions.pageToken = nextPageToken
        return contacts.people.connections.list(listOptions)
    }
}


        let response = await getConnectionsList(contacts)
        let nextPage = response.data.nextPageToken
        let connections = response.data.connections

        while (nextPage) {
            nextPage = await getConnectionsList(contacts, nextPage)
            connections.push(nextPage.data.connections) // not working
            connections.concat(nextPage.data.connections) // also not working...  

            nextPage = nextPage.data.nextPageToken
            console.log('hasNextPage?', nextPage)
        }

        console.log('connections',connections)

        resolve(connections)
```

Comment: Do you see any error message while running your code? Or you just don't see any changes after running it?

Comment: I´ve restarted the operational system and just worked... I guess there is some session open that even closing the browser is not enough... I´ve had to restart the OS

Comment: Yeah, might have been something cached by your browser... Who knows? Great to hear your problem is solved!